# Schedule datetime intervals via different skipping methods

Tags: python, datetime, scheduling, intervals

I have a list of datetime intervals (start and end time). The datetime intervals have some additional attributes (see *schedule*).
Because of sorting I already have kind of ascending schedule of the intervals.
Now I want to implement some methods to deal with overlapping conflicts.
There should be run only one task per time. Overlapping tasks shall be skipped not be shifted or delayed.

These scheduling methods should be something like

- FCFS (first come, first serve): should be clear
- maximum value of an attribute like priority
- longest duration of an event (which should be similar to maximum value)

So assume we have events like Event(Interval, priority): A(0-7, 2), B(5-10, 3), C(8-15,1), D(20-25,0).
Higher value, higher priority.

FCFS: A, C, D - Maximum priority: B, D - Longest duration: A, C, D

This was my first approach for FCFS. I think it's a bad approach - for other methods as well, because I need kind of reverse-lookup not only just the last event.

Sample data:

```py
start1 = datetime.now()
start2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=40)
start3 = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=70)
start4 = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=200)

schedule = [{"start": start1,
             "end": start1 + timedelta(seconds=60),
             "name": "Task1",
             "attr": 2},
            {"start": start2,
             "end": start2 + timedelta(seconds=60),
             "name": "Task2",
             "attr": 3},
            {"start": start3,
             "end": start3 + timedelta(seconds=60),
             "name": "Task3",
             "attr": 1},
            {"start": start4,
             "end": start4 + timedelta(seconds=60),
             "name": "Task4",
             "attr": 0}
            ]
```

The helper calss DateTimeInterval. For the difference I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721249/python-date-interval-intersection).

```
class DateTimeInterval(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __sub__(self, other):
        latest_start = max(self.start, other.start)
        earliest_end = min(self.end, other.end)
        return earliest_end - latest_start
```

Scheduling for FCFS

```
# now we can order the beginnings
schedule_sorted = sorted(schedule, key=lambda x: (x["start"], x["name"]))

last = None
for job in schedule_sorted:
    interval = DateTimeInterval(job["start"], job["end"])
    # if there is a last entry
    if last:
        interval_last = DateTimeInterval(last["start"], last["end"])
        diff = interval - interval_last
        if diff.total_seconds() > 0:
            logging.warn("%s CONFLICT OVERLAPPING %s!", job["name"], diff)
        else:
            last = job
    else:
        last = job
    logging.info("%s: %s %s", job["name"], job["start"], job["end"])
```

I could may hack all the methods resulting in some ugly piece of code.

Has anyone (dealt with implementing such different scheduling requirements yet and) know a pretty way to do that?

Comment: For FCFS should the key (example datetime(start1)) be oldest to be the first one? Is the attr value an integer? Is duration calculated by the difference of schedule[key]["end"] and schedule[key]["start"]?

Comment: Yes for FCFS first start will win. Attr is most likely an integer. The duration is calculated by the difference. And calculate the overlapping is implemented in a `__sub__` method of DateTimeInterval like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721249/python-date-interval-intersection).

Comment: I suggest you start looking at python min and max functions. Use the key parameter that let's you decide the sort criteria by a custom function. You can compare the dictionary elements as you wish in that custome function. See an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833373/python-max-value-in-a-dictionary-with-2-keys/26834605#26834605

Comment: Also add few real values in the schedule dictionary and the expected out put in each case. That will help to play around with and provide a solution.

Comment: @user3885927 Did that. Simplify a bit and correct some mistakes I did during editing for this posting here. I don't know if that is clear. There is only one ressource with one job which can run at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your explanation for the other methods, I think you should change your approach. Instead of sorting by start time, you should first sort the events by your resolution criterion (FCFS, Longest duration or Priority). Then, you should have a method `schedule_event()` which would either insert one event into a sorted list of scheduled events or drop the events.

The initial sorting we do ensures that all higher priority events get scheduled first and lower priority one can then be dropped in case of conflicts. Some skeleton code here:

```
def sort_events(method_name, events):
  ######
  return sorted_events

def schedule_event(event, scheduled_events):
  if not len(scheduled_events):
    scheduled_events.append(event)
    return
  right_index = bisect.bisect(scheduled_events, event)
  left_index = right_index - 1
  if len(scheduled_events) == right_index:
    if event.conflicts(scheduled_events[left_index]):
      return
  else:
    if event.conflicts(scheduled_events[left_index]) or event.conflicts(scheduled_events[right_index]):
      return
  bisect.insort(scheduled_events, event)

def main():
  scheduled_events = []
  sorted_events = sort_events("FCFS", events)
  for event in sorted_events:
    schedule_event(event, scheduled_events)
```

You should maintain the events in the `scheduled_events` list in a sorted order. Maintain them in start time order. You can use the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to find out if there are any conflicts while inserting. Use `bisect.bisect()` to find the insertion point and check for conflicts both to the immediate left and immediate right. To the left, the end time should be before the start time of current event. To the right, the start time should be after the end time of current event. If no conflict, insert using `bisect.insort()` Else, do nothing.

Also, in order to make sorting possible, you need to define your own Event class instead of using a dictionary and implement an `__lt__()` method in that class.

```
class Event:
  def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
    self.start_time = start_time
    self.end_time = end_time

  def __lt__(self,):
    pass
```

Comment: Yes, it's not just a one-looper. FCFS just the first wins. If the duration should win, the task in a overall conflict interval wins with the longest duration. If then others can also run these should also added again too. May it will make it easier: I want to schedule an satellite passes for an antenne.

Comment: Added an example, hope that helps. Just B, single event counts, not the duration overall.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, different sorting is the easy way to go I think. I'm interested in a good way for schedule_event... how do I write the criteria to insert or not? That's the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah, you should use `bisect.bisect()` to find the insertion point and check for conflicts both to the immediate left and right. To the left, the end time should be before the start time of current event. To the right, the start time should be after the end time of current event. If no conflict, insert using `bisect.insort()` Else, do nothing.

Comment: Ok, but how should I evaluate the overlaping? bisect just compares items and no datetime intervals... sorry spent already hours for this. I not to see the wood for the trees.

Comment: Thank you. It's not working like that... `bisect.bisect` can't know what it have to result. And also what about if the list is empty in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, you should handle that special case as you did in the pastebin code that you shared. But, you should first convert the event dictionaries into custom objects that are sortable by implementing the `__lt__` method. This way `bisect` can know how to sort them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64674/discussion-between-phani-and-wenzul).

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, Tweak your lambda function as you need. I just showed you how o do min but max is exactly similar. Documentations for min is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#min)

```
ByFCFS = min(schedule,key=lambda k:k["start"])
ByAttr= min(schedule,key=lambda k:k["attr"])
ByTimeDiff = min(schedule,key=lambda k:k["end"]-k["start"])

>>> ByFCFS
{'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 32, 54, 151000), 'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 33, 54, 151000), 'name': 'Task1', 'attr': 2}
>>> ByAttr
{'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 36, 14, 152000), 'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 37, 14, 152000), 'name': 'Task4', 'attr': 0}
>>> ByTimeDiff
{'start': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 32, 54, 151000), 'end': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 10, 20, 33, 54, 151000), 'name': 'Task1', 'attr': 2}
>>>
```

Note that this will return the first record if there are many minimums as in the example of ByTimeDiff. If you need to do max, replace min with max.

Comment: Thanks for your response. May it is not clear what I want. The time is the measure. I don't want just to sort it. I want every time sort it by time. Just the collisions I want to resolve with a suitable heuristic. The min, max functions are clear to me. It's the method to schedule with a lookup in the future what to ignore or what to use.